# Check whether a reverse iterator has crossed forward iterator or not

Tags: c++

I have a `vector<int>::iterator` and a `vector<int>::reverse_iterator` as shown:

```
vector<int>::iterator start = array.begin();
vector<int>::reverse_iterator end = array.rend();
while (true)
{
    if (*start == *end && start <= end)
    {
        start++;
        end++;
    }
}
```

In the while loop I have to check if the values at start and end are equal as well as start has not crossed end. Doing so in `start <= end` is giving me error. Can someone guide me through the right method?

The error:

> start <= end . Binary operator '<=' cant be applied to the expressions of type vector::iterator and reverse_iterator .

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: start <= end . Binary operator '<=' cant be applied to the expressions of type vector<int>::iterator and reverse_iterator . PS. I am coding in CLion

Comment: You'll need to get the `.base()` of the reverse iterator before you are allowed to compare them. This might get a bit tricky depending on what you want to do. There's an off-by-1 in there that is sometimes surprising.

Comment: `rend` points at the start of the range, not the end. It's the end of the reversed range.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6673775/2405914), "All iterators are equality comparable. Only random access iterators are relationally comparable. Input iterators, forward iterators, and bidirectional iterators are not relationally comparable."

Comment: the error message should be included in the question

Comment: how about `array.begin() - start <= array.rend() - end`? you can't compare iterators of different type

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado - The iterators have to be of the same type to be any type of comparable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The code:**

```
std::vector<int> test_vector{0, 1, 2, 3};
std::vector<int>::iterator left_it = test_vector.begin();
std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator right_it = test_vector.rbegin();
while (std::distance(left_it, right_it.base() - 1) > 0) {
  ++left_it;
  ++right_it;
}
std::cout << "Iterators crossed" << std::endl;
std::cout << "*left_it = " << *left_it << ", *right_it = " << *right_it << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
Iterators crossed
*left_it = 2, *right_it = 1
```

We use [`std::distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) in combination with [`std::reverse_iterator::base()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator/base) to determine the relative positions of the two iterators.  If the distance is zero, the iterators have reached the same element; if the distance is negative, they have crossed.

(Note: the negative case requires **C++11 or later**, calling `std::distance` with the first parameter "after" the second was **undefined behavior before C++11**).

---

**Explanation:**

In order to get a basis on which to compare reverse iterators to forward iterators, we need to use the [`std::reverse_iterator::base()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator/base) function.  However, due to an implementation trick (see below for why) used by reverse iterators, this gives you a result that's one element to the right of what you might expect.

To demonstrate briefly, we can iterate through a vector and check the offset of the current address from the address of the vector's first element.  First forwards, we have:

```
std::vector<int> test_vector{0, 1, 2, 3};
for (auto it = test_vector.begin(); it != test_vector.end(); ++it) {
  std::cout << &*it - &test_vector.front() << " ";
}
```

which outputs the following as expected.

```
0 1 2 3
```

If we go backwards, the output is reversed:

```
for (auto rit = test_vector.rbegin(); rit != test_vector.rend(); ++rit) {
  std::cout << &*rit - &test_vector.front() << " ";
}
```

yields

```
3 2 1 0
```

**However**, if we check the **address of the `std::reverse_iterator::base()` iterator instead**, we see something different:

```
for (auto rit = test_vector.rbegin(); rit != test_vector.rend(); ++rit) {
  std::cout << &*rit.base() - &test_vector.front() << " ";
}
```

yields

```
4 3 2 1
```

So, we need to subtract `1` from the address of the `.base()` iterator to get the correct corresponding forwards iterator.  This is confirmed by the line from the documentation given below (however, I found their explanation unclear and difficult to grasp, which is why I decided to experiment tangibly):

> That is `&*(rit.base() - 1) == &*rit`.

I couldn't possibly summarize this better than [Mankarse's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/633225/7022459) does:

> A simple way of thinking about iterators is that they are cursors at
>   positions between elements. A forwards iterator will produce the
>   element after the cursor when dereferenced, a reverse iterator will
>   produce the element before the cursor when dereferenced. Equivalent
>   forwards and reverse iterators are cursors that are at the same
>   position.

---

**Why off by one?**

It may seem strange to you that reverse iterators have this innate off-by-1 discrepancy.  It seems as though when a reverse iterator is at position `i`, it's actually pointing to the element at position `i-1`, i.e. the element **before** `i`.

There's an innate asymmetry in iterators that can explain this.  Consider forward iterators: what are the "earliest" and "latest" iterators we can have?

The earliest iterator is the iterator pointing to the first element, while the latest iterator points *after the last element* of the collection.

When we iterate in reverse, we need this same functionality in reverse.  Our earliest reverse iterator should point **directly** to the last element, and our latest reverse iterator must point **before** the first element (or from a reversed perspective, after the first element).  These are the basic semantics that allow us to iterate through the collection and know when we have visited every element.

We now see the natural correspondence between the forward and reverse views induces this off-by-one effect.  If we envision our collection sequenced from left to right, the **last element** lies at the **second to rightmost** position visited in forwards order but the **rightmost** position visited in reverse order.  However, the **first element** lies at the **leftmost position** in forwards order and the **second to leftmost** position in reverse order.

Here is a concrete example.  When our reverse iterator's `base` corresponds to position `0`, that indicates it has already gone past the beginning (or the reverse end) and is done iterating.  So it points to the element at position `0` 
 one step earlier, which occurs when its `base` is at position `1`.  However, the forward iterator simply references the element at position `0` when it is at position `0`.

Comment: Should be accepted as the best answer imo

Answer (score 3):

Vokay, I've solved it and here is how I did it:

```
    vector<int>::iterator start = array.begin();
    vector<int>::reverse_iterator end = array.rbegin();
    while (true)
    {
        if (*start == *end && start <= end.base())
        {
            start++;
            end++;
        }
        else
            break;
    }
```

I replaced rend with rbegin, because that is where things were going wrong

Comment: What happened to the answer that first mentioned base()?

Comment: He deleted that answer

Comment: This isn’t quite correct; a reverse iterator [points to a different element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator/base) than its `base` non-reverse iterator, so this introduces an off-by-one error.

Answer (score 2):

A contiguous iterator is not much over a pointer wrapper, and finding the pointed object is just a matter of taking the address of the object *pointed at* by the iterator. So you can just do:

```
if (*start == *end && &(*start) <= &(*end)) { ...
```

Provided you are iterating over a contiguous container like a `std::array` or a `std::vector`, the pointers actually point to elements of the same underlying raw array, so comparing the pointers is valid. And if you were iterating over a non contiguous container, comparing iterators would not make sense at all...

Comment: Comparing iterators makes perfect sense for any random-access iterator, not just a contiguous one.

Comment: @DanielH: Are you sure? A `std::list` does not allow fast random access to its elements, which means that they are not required to be contiguous so they could be randomly allocated. In that case, comparing the addresses of two elements would compare the addresses of 2 unrelated objects which is explicitely Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: You’re right; I was thinking of just equality comparison, not less-than comparison. I edited my comment. Non-contiguous containers don’t support straight less-than comparison of pointers (as in, it’s undefined behavior, not just random—you can’t legally compare pointers to different objects with `<`, even though you can with `std::less`), but it still makes sense to do compare iterators for some of them.